# Recursively Distribute Rows in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update, recursive-query

I have problem to device a query which will be used to obtain information from existing rows for other rows.

Existing table data

[image]

In above image there are three rows for RecptNo 20100001182.

In Recptno 20100001182 i have three cheques
Cheque Nos 000005,000006,000007 for Instno 5,6,7 respectively

[image]

The cheques of recptno 20100001182 are returned using Recptno 20100001970

But recptno 20100001970 does not capture instno so need to distribute matching cheque no in both recpt.

Desired Output

[image]

- When a bounce or negative entry is done which is identified by
  negative amount and Type="O".
- The -ve amount should be distributed with respect to existing +ve amount rows which exist before that date and having same chqno (in case of cheque) or if there is no cheque number
  than amount of highest Instno should be picked first and then descending
  instno until total amount is distributed.

Now in RecptNo 20100001971 the amount is received to cover up the returned cheques.

[image]

The amount received in RecptNo 20100001971 need to be properly divided. Now when Type="O" and amount is positive than we should pick Minimum Instno first and then pick rest in ascending order, until total amount is properly divided.

Desired Result should have been as below.
[image]

What i have tried
It is complicated may be it would be readable

```
    DECLARE @sign as int
DECLARE @CHKREGNO AS VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @PayModeID  varchar(30),
@StdledgerID    varchar(10),
@RecptKey   varchar(30),
@InstType   varchar(1),
@BaseAmount bigint,
@PayModeType    varchar(10),
@LedgerDate datetime,
@InstNo int,
@RegNo  varchar(30),
@PostDate   datetime,
@ServiceTax bigint,
@Dvat   bigint,
@Concession money,
@PaymentStatus  int,
@CenterID   varchar(10),
@ddChqCardNo    varchar(20),
@IsMarketing    bit,
@ThirdPartyTransDate    datetime,
@ThirdPartyPsnName  varchar(100),
@ThirdPartyTransLoc varchar(100),
@ThirdPartyName varchar(100),
@DDChqCardDt    datetime,
@Lumpsump   money,
@STaxPer    money,
@ConcessionWTax money,
@LumpsumpWTax   money,
@refInstno  int,
@refStdLedgerId int,
@refPayModeId   varchar(20),
@refConcession  money,
@refLumpsump    money,
@refConcessionDtl   money,
@refLumpsumpDtl money,
@STAX   decimal,
@RN INT 


DECLARE @PayModeID2 varchar(30),
@StdledgerID2   varchar(10),
@RecptKey2  varchar(30),
@InstType2  varchar(1),
@BaseAmount2    bigint,
@PayModeType2   varchar(10),
@LedgerDate2    datetime,
@InstNo2    int,
@RegNo2 varchar(30),
@PostDate2  datetime,
@ServiceTax2    bigint,
@Dvat2  bigint,
@Concession2    money,
@PaymentStatus2 int,
@CenterID2  varchar(10),
@ddChqCardNo2   varchar(20),
@IsMarketing2   bit,
@ThirdPartyTransDate2   datetime,
@ThirdPartyPsnName2 varchar(100),
@ThirdPartyTransLoc2    varchar(100),
@ThirdPartyName2    varchar(100),
@DDChqCardDt2   datetime,
@Lumpsump2  money,
@STaxPer2   money,
@ConcessionWTax2    money,
@LumpsumpWTax2  money,
@refInstno2 int,
@refStdLedgerId2    int,
@refPayModeId2  varchar(20),
@refConcession2 money,
@refLumpsump2   money,
@refConcessionDtl2  money,
@refLumpsumpDtl2    money,
@STAX2  decimal,
@RN2 INT, 
@finalamount    bigint,
@finalStax  bigint,
@finalDVat  bigint,
@base   money,
@setax  money,
@devat  money

SET @CHKREGNO='My Regno'
DECLARE @records CURSOR
SET @records= Cursor FOR select row_number() over (Order by regno,Ledgerdate,case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end) as rn,* from Payment_Ledger_Matching_bkp2 where regno=@CHKREGNO
OPEN @RECORDS
FETCH NEXT FROM @RECORDS INTO @RN,@PayModeID,@StdledgerID,@RecptKey,@InstType,@BaseAmount,@PayModeType,@LedgerDate,@InstNo,@RegNo,@PostDate,@ServiceTax
,@Dvat,@Concession,@PaymentStatus,@CenterID,@ddChqCardNo,@IsMarketing,@ThirdPartyTransDate  ,@ThirdPartyPsnName ,@ThirdPartyTransLoc,@ThirdPartyName
,@DDChqCardDt,@Lumpsump,@STaxPer,@ConcessionWTax,@LumpsumpWTax,@refInstno,@refStdLedgerId,@refPayModeId,@refConcession,@refLumpsump,@refConcessionDtl
,@refLumpsumpDtl,@STAX 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN 
 if @InstType='O' 
 begin
    set @sign=sign(@BaseAmount)
    --DECLARE RECORDS2 CURSOR FOR
    --  select * from Payment_Ledger_Matching_bkp2_New3     where regno=@regno and Ledgerdate<@LedgerDate and rn<@RN  and  BaseAmount>0  order by rn desc
    DECLARE RECORDS2 CURSOR dynamic  FOR
    SELECT row_number() over (Order by regno,Ledgerdate,case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end) as rn,*
    FROM Payment_Ledger_Matching_bkp2 AS BKP2
        WHERE RegNo=@RegNo and
        case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end
        <=(
        select MAX(INSTNO) from (select MAX(case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end) instno
        --,SUM(case when BaseAmount<0 then abs(BaseAmount)+abs(ServiceTax) else 0 end)
        --,SUM(case when BaseAmount>0 then BaseAmount+ServiceTax else 0 end)
         from Payment_Ledger_Matching_bkp2_NEW3 AS BKP2_NEW
        WHERE REGNO=@REGNO  AND CASE WHEN  ISNULL(@ddChqCardNo,'')='' THEN 1 when @PaymentStatus in (5,6,7) then 1 WHEN  @BaseAmount<0 and ISNULL(ddChqCardNo,'')=@ddChqCardNo THEN 1 WHEN @BaseAmount>0 then 1 ELSE 0 END=1
        and case when @paymentstatus in (5,6,7) then case when PaymentStatus=0 then 1 else 0 end else 1 end=1
        GROUP BY REGNO,case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end       
        HAVING case when @BaseAmount>0 then case WHEN SUM(bASEAMOUNT+ServiceTax)=0 THEN 1 when  (SUM(case when BaseAmount<0 then abs(BaseAmount)+abs(ServiceTax) else 0 end)>=SUM(case when BaseAmount>0 then BaseAmount+ServiceTax else 0 end) and SUM(case when BaseAmount<0 then abs(BaseAmount)+abs(ServiceTax) else 0 end)<>0) then 0 else 1 end else case when SUM(bASEAMOUNT+ServiceTax)>0 then 1 else 0 end end=1
        )as r
        ) 
        AND  CASE WHEN  ISNULL(@ddChqCardNo,'')='' THEN 1 when @PaymentStatus in (5,6,7) then 1 WHEN @BaseAmount<0 and ISNULL(ddChqCardNo,'')=@ddChqCardNo THEN 1 WHEN @BaseAmount>0 then 1 ELSE 0 END=1        
        and case when @paymentstatus in (5,6,7) then case when PaymentStatus=0 then 1 else 0 end else 1 end=1
        ORDER BY 
        case when @Baseamount>0
                then 10-case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then 
                case when instno IN (
                            select MAX(case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end) instno
        --,SUM(case when BaseAmount<0 then abs(BaseAmount)+abs(ServiceTax) else 0 end)
        --,SUM(case when BaseAmount>0 then BaseAmount+ServiceTax else 0 end)
        --,SUM(bASEAMOUNT+ServiceTax)
         from Payment_Ledger_Matching_bkp2_NEW3 AS BKP2_NEW
        WHERE REGNO=@REGNO  AND CASE WHEN  ISNULL(@ddChqCardNo,'')='' THEN 1 when @PaymentStatus in (5,6,7) then 1 WHEN  @BaseAmount<0 and ISNULL(ddChqCardNo,'')=@ddChqCardNo THEN 1 WHEN @BaseAmount>0 then 1 ELSE 0 END=1
        GROUP BY REGNO,case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end       
        HAVING case when @BaseAmount>0 then 
                    CASE WHEN SUM(bASEAMOUNT+ServiceTax)=0 THEN 1 
                    WHEN  (SUM(case when BaseAmount<0 then abs(BaseAmount)+abs(ServiceTax) else 0 end)
                                <SUM(case when BaseAmount>0 then BaseAmount+ServiceTax else 0 end) 
                    and SUM(case when BaseAmount<0 then abs(BaseAmount)+abs(ServiceTax) else 0 end)=0)
                     then 0 else 1 end 
                     else 
                        case when SUM(bASEAMOUNT+ServiceTax)>0 then 1 else 0 end 
                    end=1
                            )
                        then -2*(10-Instno)
                        else Instno end
                end 
        --when ISNULL(ddChqCardNo,'')=@ddChqCardNo then  10-case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end 
        else  case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end 
        end DESC
        ,LedgerDate
    OPEN RECORDS2;
    FETCH NEXT FROM RECORDS2 INTO @RN2,@PayModeID2,@StdledgerID2,@RecptKey2,@InstType2,@BaseAmount2,@PayModeType2,@LedgerDate2,@InstNo2,@RegNo2,@PostDate2,@ServiceTax2
,@Dvat2,@Concession2,@PaymentStatus2,@CenterID2,@ddChqCardNo2,@IsMarketing2,@ThirdPartyTransDate2,@ThirdPartyPsnName2,@ThirdPartyTransLoc2,@ThirdPartyName2
,@DDChqCardDt2,@Lumpsump2,@STaxPer2,@ConcessionWTax2,@LumpsumpWTax2,@refInstno2,@refStdLedgerId2,@refPayModeId2,@refConcession2,@refLumpsump2,@refConcessionDtl2
,@refLumpsumpDtl2,@STAX2
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN       

        if abs(@BaseAmount)>0 
        begin

            select 
             @Base=SUM(BaseAmount)--SUM(bASEAMOUNT)
            ,@setax=SUM(ServiceTax)--SUM(ServiceTax)        
            ,@devat=SUM(dvat)--SUM(Dvat)        
         from Payment_Ledger_Matching_bkp2_NEW3 AS BKP2_NEW
        WHERE REGNO=@REGNO  AND CASE WHEN  ISNULL(@ddChqCardNo,'')='' THEN 1 when @PaymentStatus in (5,6,7) then 1 WHEN  @BaseAmount<0 and ISNULL(ddChqCardNo,'')=@ddChqCardNo THEN 1 WHEN @BaseAmount>0 then 1 ELSE 0 END=1        
        and Instno=@InstNo2
        GROUP BY REGNO,case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end       
        HAVING case when @BaseAmount>0 then 
                    CASE WHEN SUM(BASEAMOUNT+ServiceTax)=0 THEN 1 
                    WHEN  (SUM(case when BaseAmount<0 then abs(BaseAmount)+abs(ServiceTax) else 0 end)
                                <SUM(case when BaseAmount>0 then BaseAmount+ServiceTax else 0 end) 
                    and SUM(case when BaseAmount<0 then abs(BaseAmount)+abs(ServiceTax) else 0 end)=0)
                     then 0 else 1 end 
                     else 
                        case when SUM(BASEAMOUNT+ServiceTax)>0 then 1 else 0 end 
                    end=1
             DECLARE @tbase  as money,@tstax as money,@tdvat as money
                    select @tbase=SUM(case when ledgerdate<@ledgerdate then bASEAMOUNT else 0 end)
                    ,@tstax=SUM(case when ledgerdate<@ledgerdate then ServiceTax else 0 end)
                    ,@tdvat=SUM(case when ledgerdate<@ledgerdate then Dvat else 0 end)
                 from Payment_Ledger_Matching_bkp2 AS BKP2_NEW
                WHERE REGNO=@REGNO  AND CASE WHEN  ISNULL(@ddChqCardNo,'')='' THEN 1 when @PaymentStatus in (5,6,7) then 1 WHEN  @BaseAmount<0 and ISNULL(ddChqCardNo,'')=@ddChqCardNo THEN 1 WHEN @BaseAmount>0 then 1 ELSE 0 END=1
                and Instno=@InstNo2
                GROUP BY REGNO,case when Insttype='R' then -2 when Insttype='A' then -1 when Insttype='I' then instno end       

            if abs(@BaseAmount)>=@Base and  @base+@SeTAX+@Devat<@tBase+@tstax+@tdvat --and @@CURSOR_ROWS >1
            begin
                set @finalamount=CASE WHEN @tBase-@Base>@BASEAMOUNT THEN @BASEAMOUNT ELSE @tBase-@Base END
                set @BaseAmount=abs(@BaseAmount)-(@tBase-@Base)--CASE WHEN @tBase-@Base>@BASEAMOUNT THEN 0 ELSE abs(@BaseAmount)-(@tBase-@Base) END

                set @finalStax=CASE WHEN @tBase-@Base>@BASEAMOUNT THEN @ServiceTax ELSE @tstax-@SeTAX END
                set @ServiceTax=abs(@ServiceTax)-(@tstax-@SeTAX)--CASE WHEN @tBase-@Base>@BASEAMOUNT THEN 0 ELSE abs(@ServiceTax)-(@tstax-@SeTAX) END

                set @finalDVat=CASE WHEN @tBase-@Base>@BASEAMOUNT THEN @Dvat ELSE @tdvat-@Devat END
                set @Dvat=abs(@Dvat)-(@tdvat-@Devat)--CASE WHEN @tBase-@Base>@BASEAMOUNT THEN 0 ELSE abs(@Dvat)-(@tdvat-@Devat) END

                SET @Base=0
            end
            else if abs(@BaseAmount)<@Base and @base+@SeTAX+@Devat=@tBase+@tstax+@tdvat and @@CURSOR_ROWS >1 and @PaymentStatus not in (5,6,7)
            begin
            FETCH NEXT FROM RECORDS2 INTO @RN2,@PayModeID2,@StdledgerID2,@RecptKey2,@InstType2,@BaseAmount2,@PayModeType2,@LedgerDate2,@InstNo2,@RegNo2,@PostDate2,@ServiceTax2
,@Dvat2,@Concession2,@PaymentStatus2,@CenterID2,@ddChqCardNo2,@IsMarketing2,@ThirdPartyTransDate2,@ThirdPartyPsnName2,@ThirdPartyTransLoc2,@ThirdPartyName2
,@DDChqCardDt2,@Lumpsump2,@STaxPer2,@ConcessionWTax2,@LumpsumpWTax2,@refInstno2,@refStdLedgerId2,@refPayModeId2,@refConcession2,@refLumpsump2,@refConcessionDtl2
,@refLumpsumpDtl2,@STAX2
                continue;
            end
            else if abs(@BaseAmount)>=@BaseAmount2
            begin

                set @finalamount=@BaseAmount2
                set @BaseAmount=abs(@BaseAmount)-@BaseAmount2

                set @finalStax=@ServiceTax2
                set @ServiceTax=abs(@ServiceTax)-@ServiceTax2

                set @finalDVat=@Dvat2
                set @Dvat=abs(@Dvat)-@Dvat2

                SET @BaseAmount2=0
            end
            else
            begin
                set @finalamount=abs(@BaseAmount)
                SET @BaseAmount2=@BaseAmount2-@BaseAmount
                set @BaseAmount=0

                set @finalStax=@ServiceTax
                SET @ServiceTax2=@ServiceTax2-@ServiceTax
                set @ServiceTax=0

                set @finalDVat=@Dvat
                SET @Dvat2=@Dvat2-@Dvat
                set @Dvat=0


            end

            insert into Payment_Ledger_Matching_bkp2_New3 values
            (
                @PayModeID,@StdledgerID,@RecptKey2,@InstType2,@sign*@finalamount,@PayModeType
                ,@LedgerDate,@InstNo2,@RegNo2
                ,@PostDate,@sign*@finalStax,@sign*@finalDVat,@Concession2
                ,@PaymentStatus,@CenterID2,@ddChqCardNo,
                @IsMarketing2,@ThirdPartyTransDate2,@ThirdPartyPsnName2,@ThirdPartyTransLoc2,@ThirdPartyName2
                ,@DDChqCardDt
                ,@Lumpsump2,@STaxPer2,@ConcessionWTax2,
                @LumpsumpWTax2,@refInstno2,@refStdLedgerId,@refPayModeId2,@refConcession2,@refLumpsump2,@refConcessionDtl2,@refLumpsumpDtl2,@STAX2,@rn
            )

        end
        if(@BaseAmount=0) --BREAK;
        BEGIN
            IF (@BaseAmount2>0 ) and @@CURSOR_ROWS >1 and @BaseAmount2+@ServiceTax2+@Dvat2<>@Base+@setax+@devat
            BEGIN
                FETCH NEXT FROM @RECORDS INTO @RN,@PayModeID,@StdledgerID,@RecptKey,@InstType,@BaseAmount,@PayModeType,@LedgerDate,@InstNo,@RegNo,@PostDate,@ServiceTax,@Dvat,@Concession,@PaymentStatus,@CenterID,@ddChqCardNo,
@IsMarketing,@ThirdPartyTransDate   ,@ThirdPartyPsnName ,@ThirdPartyTransLoc    ,@ThirdPartyName    ,@DDChqCardDt   ,@Lumpsump  ,@STaxPer   ,@ConcessionWTax,
@LumpsumpWTax,@refInstno,@refStdLedgerId,@refPayModeId  ,@refConcession ,@refLumpsump,@refConcessionDtl,@refLumpsumpDtl,@STAX
                set @sign=sign(@BaseAmount)
            END             

            ELSE IF @BaseAmount<0 
            BEGIN

                FETCH NEXT FROM @RECORDS INTO @RN,@PayModeID,@StdledgerID,@RecptKey,@InstType,@BaseAmount,@PayModeType,@LedgerDate,@InstNo,@RegNo,@PostDate,@ServiceTax,@Dvat,@Concession,@PaymentStatus,@CenterID,@ddChqCardNo,
@IsMarketing,@ThirdPartyTransDate   ,@ThirdPartyPsnName ,@ThirdPartyTransLoc    ,@ThirdPartyName    ,@DDChqCardDt   ,@Lumpsump  ,@STaxPer   ,@ConcessionWTax,
@LumpsumpWTax,@refInstno,@refStdLedgerId,@refPayModeId  ,@refConcession ,@refLumpsump,@refConcessionDtl,@refLumpsumpDtl,@STAX
                set @sign=sign(@BaseAmount)
                CONTINUE;
            END     
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                BREAK;
            END

        END
        ELSE IF @BaseAmount<0 and @sign>0 and @@CURSOR_ROWS >1
        BEGIN
                FETCH NEXT FROM @RECORDS INTO @RN,@PayModeID,@StdledgerID,@RecptKey,@InstType,@BaseAmount,@PayModeType,@LedgerDate,@InstNo,@RegNo,@PostDate,@ServiceTax,@Dvat,@Concession,@PaymentStatus,@CenterID,@ddChqCardNo,
@IsMarketing,@ThirdPartyTransDate   ,@ThirdPartyPsnName ,@ThirdPartyTransLoc    ,@ThirdPartyName    ,@DDChqCardDt   ,@Lumpsump  ,@STaxPer   ,@ConcessionWTax,
@LumpsumpWTax,@refInstno,@refStdLedgerId,@refPayModeId  ,@refConcession ,@refLumpsump,@refConcessionDtl,@refLumpsumpDtl,@STAX
                set @sign=sign(@BaseAmount)
                CONTINUE;
        END;

            FETCH NEXT FROM RECORDS2 INTO @RN2,@PayModeID2,@StdledgerID2,@RecptKey2,@InstType2,@BaseAmount2,@PayModeType2,@LedgerDate2,@InstNo2,@RegNo2,@PostDate2,@ServiceTax2
,@Dvat2,@Concession2,@PaymentStatus2,@CenterID2,@ddChqCardNo2,@IsMarketing2,@ThirdPartyTransDate2,@ThirdPartyPsnName2,@ThirdPartyTransLoc2,@ThirdPartyName2
,@DDChqCardDt2,@Lumpsump2,@STaxPer2,@ConcessionWTax2,@LumpsumpWTax2,@refInstno2,@refStdLedgerId2,@refPayModeId2,@refConcession2,@refLumpsump2,@refConcessionDtl2
,@refLumpsumpDtl2,@STAX2
    END;
    CLOSE RECORDS2;
    DEALLOCATE RECORDS2;

 end
 else
 begin
    insert into Payment_Ledger_Matching_bkp2_New3 values
    (
        @PayModeID,@StdledgerID,@RecptKey,@InstType,@BaseAmount,@PayModeType,@LedgerDate,@InstNo,@RegNo,@PostDate,@ServiceTax,@Dvat,@Concession,@PaymentStatus,@CenterID,@ddChqCardNo,
        @IsMarketing,@ThirdPartyTransDate   ,@ThirdPartyPsnName ,@ThirdPartyTransLoc    ,@ThirdPartyName    ,@DDChqCardDt   ,@Lumpsump  ,@STaxPer   ,@ConcessionWTax,
        @LumpsumpWTax,@refInstno    ,@refStdLedgerId,@refPayModeId  ,@refConcession ,@refLumpsump,@refConcessionDtl,@refLumpsumpDtl,@STAX,@rn
    )
end
FETCH NEXT FROM @RECORDS INTO @RN,@PayModeID,@StdledgerID,@RecptKey,@InstType,@BaseAmount,@PayModeType,@LedgerDate,@InstNo,@RegNo,@PostDate,@ServiceTax,@Dvat,@Concession,@PaymentStatus,@CenterID,@ddChqCardNo,
@IsMarketing,@ThirdPartyTransDate   ,@ThirdPartyPsnName ,@ThirdPartyTransLoc    ,@ThirdPartyName    ,@DDChqCardDt   ,@Lumpsump  ,@STaxPer   ,@ConcessionWTax,
@LumpsumpWTax,@refInstno,@refStdLedgerId,@refPayModeId  ,@refConcession ,@refLumpsump,@refConcessionDtl,@refLumpsumpDtl,@STAX

END
close @RECORDS
deallocate @RECORDS;

select sum(Baseamount) over (partition by Regno),* from Payment_Ledger_Matching_bkp2_New3
```

- [SQLFiddle for Sample data to process](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4acf/2)
- [SQlFiddle for desired output of sample of above sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/510aa/1)

Comment: Having trouble to understand what you need. What is your query so far? How do you find recptno 20100001970?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Actually the case i represented is for one user. So the transactions showed are pertaining to one user and transaction are mainy oof three type I, O -ve amount,O +ve amount

Comment: @MaciejLos I have updated my question with what i have tried

Comment: @AmritpalSingh, Still can't get your logic ;( Do you want to calculate running sum? In case of RcptNo=20100001971, what you devide and by what?

Comment: @MaciejLos Can we chat i will explain

Comment: @AmritpalSingh, well... i do not practice that. Please, don't get me wrong. Nothing personal, just a rule. Try to explain it step by step.

Comment: @MaciejLos I have tried to put case in best way possible with step by step execution required.

Comment: I say the same to @MaciejLos, what is your criteria division, why in the amount of 20100001971 cheques the have values like 12350, 1900, etc. and why just one instno 7 in the last row... and no pair rows like the other 5 and 6.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Because After -ve entry lesser amount is recieved.

Comment: This could be done set based but this is way beyond the scope of online forum. This would take 2-3 days at a minimum to even get close and that doesn't include creating test cases to use as validation. The bigger issue I see is that you seem to have a bunch of business rules rolled into your sql. This does not lend itself to good separation of duties.

Comment: @SeanLange Rightly said, I just need some idea in this direction. That would have helped. Actually this logic is required on legacy data which does not captured information in the way it is required.

Comment: @AmritpalSingh, you are saying that this is legacy data, which means that it doesn't change. I would write a not efficient, but simple and easy to verify script and do a one-off processing of legacy data. Since it is a one-off run it doesn't matter if it is set-based, or using cursors, or even export your data into Excel and do it there. This kind of logic is much easier to do in a procedural programming language with proper arrays.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov yes quite right, Procedural way i have done it. but take a lot of time for execution, So thought an inline mechanism could have helped.

Comment: since this is legacy and unchanging data and you have something that already works I would just run it and be done with it. Do it during a slow period, maybe add some waits in the middle of your looping to ease pressure during execution so other threads can still run. To make this set based requires a change in how you think about data. You have think about what you want to do to a column instead of what you want to do to each row. Even coming up with some ideas would require a couple hours to fully understand what this is doing.

Comment: @SeanLange Fair enough

Comment: you have definitely not provided sufficient sample data.Check your last desired output sample.For this output sample,is there any input sample ?For cheque no 20100001970  and rcptno 000007,how come the amount is 14251.First two images are clear.But colored images are not clear.Just provided 9-10 rows of input sample data with different criteria.and next show desired output.

Comment: "The cheques of recptno 20100001182 are returned using Recptno 20100001970" .Check your 1st image there only 3 rows.Then How do i know if i hv to use 20100001970 against 20100001182 .Do you mean to say that returned Recptno is already there in table.We just hv to update Amount column based on certain criteria .We can identify returned RecptNo using InstNo and ChqNo .Am I right ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh I have used information of one person only for showing the scenario and step by step execution. There is one vendor id. which identifies which receipt belong to which vendor

Comment: you hv not answered few of my queries above.I repeat.what is your input sample data.(as it appear in table) and what is your desired output.I am more confuse on input sample.I think everything is already in table only amount need to be updated as per requirement .Am I right  ?Once again throw input and output.and keep this thread alive for 2-3 days more.

Comment: @KumarHarsh I have setup a table in sql fiddle Please check for input values http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4acf/2

Comment: @KumarHarsh I have created SQL fiddle of desired Result http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/510aa/1,

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying what I understood.So don't DOWNVOTE.

Most importantly,I am not seeing any desire output .If you provide,then it will help in understanding quickly .

What I understood,

1. One need to update BaseAmount where InstType='O' and all other condition that you mention.
2. No need of updating  BaseAmount where InstType<>'O'.It just help in updating point 1 above.InstType like 'I','R','A' serve the same purpose in this requirement.
3. According to your explanation there is only two type of InstType for this requirement i.e. 'O' and other.
4. So if above are true then there are only 3 condition

   i) InstType 'O' with chequeNo ii) InstType 'O' with Negative BaseAmount 
   iii) InstType 'O' with Positive BaseAmount

   So base on fiddle sample data.It can be definetly done without cursor and can be further optimize provided things are more clear .

> ```
> ;WITH ChequeCTE AS
>  (
>  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ddChqCardNo,iNSTTYPE Order by regno,Ledgerdate ) as rn
>  ,[RecptKey], [InstType],[BaseAmount],[PayModeType],[LedgerDate],[InstNo],[Regno]
>  ,[PostDate],[ServiceTax],[DVAT],[Concession],[PaymentStatus],[CenterId],[ddChqCardNo]
>  ,[ddChqCardDt],[Lumpsump],[RowId],[concDtlsId],[concDiff]
>  FROM @Matching_Table AS BKP2 WHERE  ISNUMERIC(ddChqCardNo)=1
>  )
>  ,ChequeCTE1 AS
>  (
>   SELECT RN,[RecptKey],
>   [InstType],
>   (SELECT B.[BaseAmount] FROM ChequeCTE B WHERE [InstType]<>'O' 
>   AND A.RN=B.RN AND A.[ddChqCardNo]=B.[ddChqCardNo] )[BaseAmount],
>   [PayModeType],[LedgerDate],[InstNo],[Regno],[PostDate],[ServiceTax],[DVAT]
>   ,[Concession],[PaymentStatus],[CenterId],[ddChqCardNo],[ddChqCardDt],[Lumpsump],[RowId]
>   ,[concDtlsId],[concDiff]
>   FROM ChequeCTE A WHERE INSTTYPE='O' AND ISNUMERIC(ddChqCardNo)=1
>  )
>  ,NonChequeCTE_NotO_MinInstNo AS
>  (
>  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over ( Order by regno ,[InstNo]  ) as rn,[RecptKey],
>   [InstType],[BaseAmount],[PayModeType],[LedgerDate],[InstNo],[Regno],[PostDate]
>   ,[ServiceTax],[DVAT]
>   ,[Concession],[PaymentStatus],[CenterId],[ddChqCardNo],[ddChqCardDt],[Lumpsump]
>   ,[RowId],[concDtlsId],[concDiff]
>  FROM @Matching_Table AS BKP2 WHERE  ISNUMERIC(ddChqCardNo)=0 and [InstType]<>'O'
>  )
>  ,NonChequeCTE_NotO_MaxInstNo AS
>  (
>  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over ( Order by regno ,[InstNo] desc  ) as rn,[RecptKey],
>   [InstType],[BaseAmount],[PayModeType],[LedgerDate],[InstNo],[Regno],[PostDate]
>   ,[ServiceTax],[DVAT]
>   ,[Concession],[PaymentStatus],[CenterId],[ddChqCardNo],[ddChqCardDt],[Lumpsump]
>   ,[RowId],[concDtlsId],[concDiff]
>  FROM @Matching_Table AS BKP2 WHERE  ISNUMERIC(ddChqCardNo)=0 and [InstType]<>'O'
>  )
>  ,NonChequeCTE_O_PosAmount AS
>  (
>  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over ( Order by regno,Ledgerdate ) as rn,[RecptKey],
>   [InstType],[BaseAmount],[PayModeType],[LedgerDate],[InstNo],[Regno],[PostDate]
>   ,[ServiceTax],[DVAT]
>   ,[Concession],[PaymentStatus],[CenterId],[ddChqCardNo],[ddChqCardDt],[Lumpsump]
>   ,[RowId],[concDtlsId],[concDiff]
>  FROM @Matching_Table AS BKP2 WHERE  ISNUMERIC(ddChqCardNo)=0 and [InstType]='O' and [BaseAmount]>=0
>  )
>  ,NonChequeCTE_O_NegAmount AS
>  (
>  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over ( Order by regno,Ledgerdate ) as rn,[RecptKey],
>   [InstType],[BaseAmount],[PayModeType],[LedgerDate],[InstNo],[Regno],[PostDate]
>   ,[ServiceTax],[DVAT]
>   ,[Concession],[PaymentStatus],[CenterId],[ddChqCardNo],[ddChqCardDt],[Lumpsump]
>   ,[RowId],[concDtlsId],[concDiff]
>  FROM @Matching_Table AS BKP2 WHERE  ISNUMERIC(ddChqCardNo)=0 and [InstType]='O' and [BaseAmount]<0
>  )
>  ,UpdateNonChequeCTE_O_PosAmount AS
>  (
>    SELECT A.rn,A.[RecptKey],
>   A.[InstType],
>   --(SELECT B.[BaseAmount] FROM NonChequeCTE_NotO_MinInstNo B WHERE   A.RN=B.RN  )[BaseAmount],
>    B.[BaseAmount] ,
>   A.[PayModeType],A.[LedgerDate],A.[InstNo],A.[Regno],A.[PostDate],A.[ServiceTax],A.[DVAT]
>   ,A.[Concession],A.[PaymentStatus],A.[CenterId],A.[ddChqCardNo],A.[ddChqCardDt]
>   ,A.[Lumpsump],A.[RowId],A.[concDtlsId],A.[concDiff]
>   FROM NonChequeCTE_O_PosAmount A 
>   INNER JOIN NonChequeCTE_NotO_MinInstNo B ON A.RN=B.RN
>  )
>  ,UpdateNonChequeCTE_O_NegAmount AS
>  (
>    SELECT A.rn,A.[RecptKey],
>   A.[InstType]
>   --(SELECT B.[BaseAmount] FROM NonChequeCTE_NotO_MaxInstNo B WHERE   A.RN=B.RN  )[BaseAmount],
>   ,B.[BaseAmount]
>   ,A.[PayModeType],A.[LedgerDate],A.[InstNo],A.[Regno],A.[PostDate],A.[ServiceTax],A.[DVAT]
>   ,A.[Concession],A.[PaymentStatus],A.[CenterId],A.[ddChqCardNo]
>   ,A.[ddChqCardDt],A.[Lumpsump],A.[RowId],A.[concDtlsId],A.[concDiff]
>   FROM NonChequeCTE_O_NegAmount A 
>   INNER JOIN NonChequeCTE_NotO_MaxInstNo B ON   A.RN=B.RN 
>  )
>
>  SELECT 1 RN, * FROM @Matching_Table WHERE INSTTYPE<>'O'
>  UNION ALL
>  SELECT * FROM ChequeCTE1
> UNION ALL
>    SELECT * FROM UpdateNonChequeCTE_O_PosAmount
> UNION ALL
>   SELECT * FROM UpdateNonChequeCTE_O_NegAmount
>
>   -- No of rows returned=no of rows in actual table
> ```

Comment: I will try use the solution provided and revert, I have shared the sqlfiddle of desired result please check in this link http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/510aa/1

Comment: @AmritpalSingh ,You yourself check the output link,data are same as input.I do not see any difference.Also there is no sample data Type='O' and amount is negative and it is not cheque.

Comment: I actually checked and then reposted. IF YOU CHECK ROW NUMBER 18,19,20,21 ST ARE NEWLY GENERATED ROWS.

Comment: sORRY for replying late,was busy.Consider recptno 0005130 type 'O' chequeno 559940 in input sample.Now in output sample i see (-10837.00 and -4830.00) for this chequeno.Just show us the calculation of output.How did this amount derive .Exactly how the figure -10837.00 got calculated and so on .you will get plenty of solution here.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever you are attempting to do appears to involve logic that would work well in a general purpose programming language.

My suggestion would be to use your favorite programming or scripting language to connect to your database and retrieve your data, manipulate it, and then present or store your results as appropriate.